# Jquery Mobile Autocomplete from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I started with the example at [Jquery Mobile Autocomplete DEMO](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/)

I just want to change so that the data displayed is coming from MySQL, but after putting three characters in my search field, I get no list values.

This is my code:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#test", function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                 url: "search2.php",
                 dataType: "jsonp",
                 crossDomain: true,
                 data: {
                    term: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val.value + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
require_once("res/mysql-connect.php");
$return = array();
if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projects limit 10"))
                 {                  
                    echo "Fail SQL:" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;                                   
                 }
                 else
                 {
$resultado->data_seek(0);
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) 
                 {
                     array_push($return, array(
        'label'      => $fila['project_name'], 
        'value'    => $fila['project_id']) );
                 }

echo(json_encode($return));
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1><? echo $labels['MAIN_PLURAL']; ?></h1>
        <a href="#menupanel" class="ui-btn-right">Opciones</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3>Cities worldwide</h3>
<p>After you enter <strong>at least three characters</strong> the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.</p>
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..." data-filter-theme="a"></ul>
        <span style="float:right"><label for="province"><?php echo 'Conectado como ' . $_SESSION['username']?></label></span>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="right">                                                                  
    <h1></h1>
    <a href="./admin/cmd.php?cmd=logout" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-right ui-corner-all" style="margin: 0;">Salir</a>   
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

var_dump($return) if I open search2.php

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'VEGA DE SAN JOSÃ‰' (length=17)
      'value' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'PARQUE DE CASABLANCA I ' (length=23)
      'value' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'PLAZA DE MIGUEL ANGEL BLANCO' (length=28)
      'value' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'EL LASSO II' (length=11)
      'value' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'PLAZA TENDERETE' (length=15)
      'value' => string '5' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'PARQUE GLORIA FUERTES' (length=21)
      'value' => string '6' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'LOS TARAHALES I' (length=15)
      'value' => string '7' (length=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'JARDINES DE CASABLANCA III' (length=26)
      'value' => string '8' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'LOMO APOLINARIO' (length=15)
      'value' => string '9' (length=1)
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      'label' => string 'CASABLANCA II' (length=13)
      'value' => string '10' (length=2)
```

Comment: Does it work without the SQL usage in the response?  If you put static responses do you receive those?

Comment: In the browser window, right click, and view page source. do you see the list items there?? is it populating the page from your jsonp call?? if not try putting --- header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  -- as the first line in your php script. if not then make a json call instead of a jsonp -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Json in stead of Jsonp is working!! :)